# Do I need a full BMS or just protection circuit?

Tags: circuit-protection, power-management

I'm planning on building a custom battery powered speaker, and am quite new to rechargeable batteries. My amplifier needs 5V, so I thought I would put 2 [18650 batteries](https://www.walmart.com/ip/4-Pack-18650-Battery-3000mAh-3-7v-Li-ion-Batteries/819300587) in series, and use [a step down module](https://www.banggood.com/Mini-DC-DC-Converter-Step-Down-Module-Adjustable-Power-Supply-p-920327.html) to get to 5V.

My question is: Do I need a full BMS, or will just [a protection circuit](https://www.banggood.com/TP4056-Micro-USB-5V-1A-Lithium-Battery-Charging-Module-Board-TE585-Lipo-Charger-p-1225993.html) do the job? Will all these components work together? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Lithium batteries need **both** **charge** control and **discharge** control.  The charge controller will do half the job. But what is protecting your batteries from being overly discharged?  What if the speaker gets left in the on state with no signal, so it's silently discharging the batteries?

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for the reply and editing the original post. Is that a yes that all the linked components will work together to power the amplifier?

Comment: Also, does it change anything if i add another pair of batteries in parallel, in order to increase the mAh?

Comment: @AWein Paralleling them should be fine: https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/serial_and_parallel_battery_configurations

Answer (score 0):

Tl;Dr:
Get yourself a BMS to protect the batteries. Either one per cell or one that is made for 2 cells or more should be fine. It should have Over Voltage, Under Voltage, and Over Current/Short Circuit Protection. You always want some type of protection for your batteries. For the charger, you'll need a charger that charges the batteries to 8.4V in series. So the one in the link will not do since it is designed for 1 battery and not 2 in series. The components will work together as long as you put them in their right location (wiring wise). So just make sure to look at the datasheets to verify how everything should be hooked up.

Post:
So typically when you are working with a project that uses Lithium Ion or LiPo batteries, you want some type of circuit that protects the batteries against Over Voltage (When the charging voltage on the batteries becomes too high), Under Voltage (When the voltage on the batteries drops below 2.5V per cell [minimum battery voltage varies by battery manufacture fyi]), and Over Current protection (i.e. over discharge from the battery via normal use or short circuit).

Firstly, what I would recommend doing is including some type of BMS to your battery pack. Anyone observing this post, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. But you can either get two BMS's per cell with the minimum features listed above, or you can get a BMS that is designed for 2 cells in series.

Secondly, if you are going to be using 2 batteries in series for this project, then the battery charging module in the link you provided isn't going to have enough voltage. For 2 batteries in series, you're going to want a charging module that charges the batteries up to 8.4V since that is the max charging voltage of 2 batteries in series.

I'm not sure how much this matters with your project, but you won't be able to use a normal USB A to Micro USB or whatever type cable since USB A ports on laptops, computers, etc. only output a 5V max output. That said, you could use some module that boosts the 5V from your USB Port, but you will have a limited output current which means your batteries will take longer to charge. You'll have to get a USB C to USB C cable with a USB C charging module that is designed with the Power Delivery protocol. But this is beyond the scope of your original question.

But in any case, you need a different battery charging module/circuit. You can either make your own by making a PCB, or you can search for modules that takes in (idk, lets say 9V minimum) input Voltage, and charges the batteries to 8.4V. I hope this helps.